# OSError: Result too large

Tags: python, scapy

I'am playing around with scapy but i cant get it to work. I tried different code's but all gave me the same output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<module1>", line 7, in <module>
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\scapy\sendrecv.py", line 357, in srp
    s = conf.L2socket(iface=iface, filter=filter, nofilter=nofilter, type=type)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\scapy\arch\pcapdnet.py", line 313, in __init__
    self.outs = dnet.eth(iface)
  File "dnet.pyx", line 112, in dnet.eth.__init__
OSError: Result too large
```

Iam using python 2.6 with all dependencies installed for scapy.

How to fix this?

Comment: See http://code.google.com/p/libdnet/issues/detail?id=6, I don't see a fix there either though.

Comment: hmm yes i have seen that but no fix :(